# Setting up MEAN stack not rendering app-root

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I'm trying to setup a basic mean stack by following this [guide](https://medium.com/@kthotav/deploying-angular-2-mean-stack-web-application-using-heroku-in-less-than-5-minutes-29b1c80d0155), but the client doesn't seem to render the app instead the body contains,

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

The file structure is exactly the same as a **blank angular** cli project **except** the addition of two extra files.

PLUS: `npm install --save ejs cors express body-parser`

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors')

var index = require('./routes/index');

// app
var app = express();

// cors
app.use(cors());

// views
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src'));

// engine
app.set('view enginer', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// angular  dist
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// body bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// route 
app.use('/', index);


// Initialize the app.
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
});
```

I run an `ng build` and `node server.js` but get a blank white page in the browser.

Perhaps there is a breaking change that I'm not aware of since that guide  was using angular2 (I'm using angular 6).

Comment: What's inside your `dist` folder?

Comment: A folder with the project name, then inside that > index.html, styles.js, vendor.js and several others. THanks

Comment: Since your `index.html` isn't directly inside the `dist` folder (rather, it is inside a sub-folder), try changing `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));` to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/<your project name here>'));`

Comment: Thats done it. Post a solution and I'll accept it. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `index.html` isn't directly inside the `dist` folder (rather, it is inside a sub-folder for some reason), try changing `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));` to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/<your project name here>'));`